# use trie data structure to solve the problem of clustering anagrams

Tags: c++, trie

> Given an array of words, print all anagrams together. For example, if
>   the given array is {“cat”, “dog”, “tac”, “god”, “act”}, then output
>   may be “cat tac act dog god”.

The following is my c++ code. I use raw pointer to implement varying number of children
for practice. Actually, I guess maybe it's better to adopt STL containers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct Index_node_base
{
    Index_node_base* next;
    Index_node_base():next(NULL){}  
};

struct Index_node : public Index_node_base
{
    int index;
    Index_node(int i):index(i), Index_node_base(){}
};

void insert_index_node(Index_node** head, int i)
{
    Index_node* node = new Index_node(i);
    node->next = (*head);
    *head = node;
}

struct Trie_node_base
{
    typedef Trie_node_base* Base_ptr;

    Base_ptr* child;
    int num_of_child;

    Trie_node_base(int n)
    {
        child = new Base_ptr[n];
        for(int i=0; i < n; ++i)
            child[i] = NULL;
        num_of_child = n;
    }

    ~Trie_node_base()
    {
        delete [] child;
    }
};

struct Trie_node : public Trie_node_base
{
    bool is_end;
    Index_node* head;
    Trie_node(int n):Trie_node_base(n), is_end(false), head(NULL){}
};

class Trie
{
public:
    Trie(int n=26)
    {
        root = new Trie_node(n);
    }
    ~Trie()
    {
        destroy(root);
    }

    void insert_trie_node(const char* w, int ind);
    Trie_node* get_root_node();

private:
    Trie_node* root;
    void destroy(Trie_node* root);
};

Trie_node* Trie::get_root_node()
{
    return root;
}

void Trie::insert_trie_node(const char* w, int ind)
{
    Trie_node* r = root;
    while(*w)
    {
        int i = *w - 'a';
        if(r->child[i] == NULL)
        {
            r->child[i] = new Trie_node(r->num_of_child);
        }
        r = (Trie_node*)r->child[i];
        ++w;
    }

    if(r->is_end)
    {
        insert_index_node(&(r->head), ind);
    }
    else
    {
        r->is_end = true;
        r->head = new Index_node(ind);
    }
}

void traversal_trie(const char* word_arr[], Trie_node* r)
{
    size_t i;

    if(r->is_end)
    {        
        Index_node* h = r->head;
        while(h != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n", word_arr[h->index]);
            h = (Index_node*)h->next;
        }
    }


    for(i = 0; i < r->num_of_child; ++i)
    {
        if(r->child[i] != NULL)
            traversal_trie(word_arr, (Trie_node*)r->child[i]);
    }    
}

void Trie::destroy(Trie_node* root)
{
    size_t i;

    for(i = 0; i < root->num_of_child; ++i)
    {
        if(root->child[i] != NULL)
            destroy((Trie_node*)root->child[i]);
    }

    if(root->is_end)
    {
        Index_node* h = root->head;
        Index_node* tmp = NULL;

        while(h != NULL)
        {
            tmp = (Index_node*)h->next;
            delete h;
            h = tmp;
        }        
    }

    delete root;
}

static int comp_char(const void* x, const void* y)
{
    const char* c1 = (const char*)x;
    const char* c2 = (const char*)y;

    return *(c1) - *(c2);
}

static void cluster_anagrams(const char* word_arr[], size_t size)
{
    Trie* trie = new Trie(26);
    size_t i;
    char* buffer;

    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        int len = strlen(word_arr[i]);
        buffer = new char [len+1];
        memcpy(buffer, word_arr[i], len+1);        
        qsort(buffer, strlen(buffer), 1, comp_char);   
        trie->insert_trie_node(buffer, i);          
        delete buffer;
    }

    cout << "Debug!" << endl;
    traversal_trie(word_arr, trie->get_root_node());
}

int main()
{
    const char* word_arr[] = {"cat", "dog", "tac", "god", "act", "gdo"};
    size_t size = sizeof(word_arr) / sizeof(word_arr[0]);
    cluster_anagrams(word_arr, size);    

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <cstring>
```

Avoid including C headers when programming C++.

```
struct Index_node_base
{
    Index_node_base* next;
    Index_node_base():next(NULL){}  
};

struct Index_node : public Index_node_base
{
    int index;
    Index_node(int i):index(i), Index_node_base(){}
};

void insert_index_node(Index_node** head, int i)
{
     Index_node* node = new Index_node(i);
     node->next = (*head);
     *head = node;
}
```

This is overkill as you are just re-implementing a list of numbers / characters.

```
const char*
```

This is C code, consider using the C++ `std::string` instead.

```
const char* word_arr[]
```

For example, this one should be a `std::list<std::string>` (a.k.a. `list<string>`)

```
 printf("%s\n", word_arr[h->index]);
```

Again C, use the C++ iostreams instead. This should be like `cout << ... << endl;`

```
while(*w)
{
    int i = *w - 'a';
    if(r->child[i] == NULL)
    {
        r->child[i] = new Trie_node(r->num_of_child);
    }
    r = (Trie_node*)r->child[i];
    ++w;
}
```

You can use iterators and STL algorithms to do this in one line.

```
for(i = 0; i < r->num_of_child; ++i)
{
    if(r->child[i] != NULL)
        traversal_trie(word_arr, (Trie_node*)r->child[i]);
}
```

This would also be one line using `for_each` on iterators and passing `traversal_trie`.

```
void Trie::destroy(Trie_node* root)
```

You won't need destory anymore as a result; also, there's a chance you might not need pointers.

```
static int comp_char(const void* x, const void* y)
{
    const char* c1 = (const char*)x;
    const char* c2 = (const char*)y;

    return *(c1) - *(c2);
}
```

This is messsy, you are doing useless C style voids and casts and not using C++ overloading. This body would have been something along the line of just the line `return c1 < c2;`

```
for(i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    int len = strlen(word_arr[i]);
    buffer = new char [len+1];
    memcpy(buffer, word_arr[i], len+1);        
    qsort(buffer, strlen(buffer), 1, comp_char);   
    trie->insert_trie_node(buffer, i);          
    delete buffer;
}
```

`memcpy`? Not necessary, `std::string` allows you to copy the string and not mess with memory.