# Implementation of Trie data structure accommodating varying number of children

Tags: c++, algorithm, interview-questions, trie

I've used the Trie data structure to solve the following problem:

> Given an array of words, print all anagrams together. For example, if the given array is {"cat", "dog", "tac", "god", "act"}, then output may be "cat tac act dog god".

The following is my C++ implementation which can accommodate varying number of children.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct Trie_node_base
{
    vector<Trie_node_base*> child;
    int num_of_child;

    Trie_node_base(int n)
    {
        num_of_child = n;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            child.push_back(NULL);
    }   
};

struct Trie_node : public Trie_node_base
{
    bool is_word;
    vector<vector<string>::const_iterator> head;

    Trie_node(int num):Trie_node_base(num), is_word(false){} 
};

class Trie
{
public:
    Trie(int n=26)
    {
        root = new Trie_node(n);
    }
    ~Trie()
    {
        destroy(root);
    }

    void insert_trie_node(const string& w, vector<string>::const_iterator ind);
    Trie_node* get_root_node()
    {
        return root;
    }

private:
    Trie_node* root;
    void destroy(Trie_node* root);
};

void Trie::insert_trie_node(const string& w, vector<string>::const_iterator ind)
{
    Trie_node* r = root;

    string::const_iterator runner = w.begin();
    for(; runner!=w.end(); ++runner)
    {
        char cur_char = *runner;
        int i = cur_char - 'a';

        if(r->child[i] == NULL)
        {
            r->child[i] = new Trie_node(r->num_of_child);
        }
        r = (Trie_node*)r->child[i];            
    }

    if(!r->is_word)
        r->is_word = true;
    r->head.push_back(ind);
}

void Trie::destroy(Trie_node* root)
{
    vector<Trie_node_base*>::iterator it = (root->child).begin();

    for(; it != (root->child).end(); ++it)
    {
        if(*it != NULL)
            destroy((Trie_node*)(*it));
    }

    delete root;
}


void traversal_trie(const vector<string>& word_arr, Trie_node* r)
{
    size_t i;

    if(r->is_word)
    {        
        vector<vector<string>::const_iterator>::iterator it = (r->head).begin();
        for(; it != (r->head).end(); ++it)
        {
            cout << *(*it) << endl;
        }        
    }


    for(i = 0; i < r->num_of_child; ++i)
    {
        if(r->child[i] != NULL)
            traversal_trie(word_arr, (Trie_node*)r->child[i]);
    }    
}

void cluster_anagrams(const vector<string>& word_arr, size_t size)
{
    Trie* trie = new Trie(26);

    vector<string>::const_iterator it = word_arr.begin();       
    for(; it != word_arr.end(); ++it)
    {
        string cur_str = *it;
        sort(cur_str.begin(), cur_str.end());
        trie->insert_trie_node(cur_str, it);        
    }     
    traversal_trie(word_arr, trie->get_root_node());
}

int main()
{
    const char* word_arr[] = {"cat", "dog", "tac", "god", "act", "gdo"};
    size_t size = sizeof(word_arr) / sizeof(word_arr[0]);    
    vector<string> word_arr1(word_arr, word_arr+size);


    cluster_anagrams(word_arr1, size);    

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Your code does several things more complex than required. In no particular order:

- What purpose does `Trie_node_base` serve? You don’t need a base class here since you only inherit from it once.
- Worse, your base class doesn’t have a virtual destructor.
- To create an array of size `n`, you use a loop and `push_back`. Much easier would be to use the proper initialiser:

  ```
  Trie_node_base(int n) :
      num_of_child(n) ,
      child(n)
      { }
  ```
- In fact, you generally fail to use initialisers, and instead re-assign values inside the constructor.
- Consider *proper naming*. In the above code snippet, it should really be `number_of_children` and `children` (plural!).
- The `num_of_child` member is redundant – the same information is stored in the vector.
- The tree node `root` doesn’t need to, and shouldn’t be, a pointer.
- In general, your use of pointers and manual memory management makes the code vastly more complex and brittle (and requires the existence of the `destroy` method). If you need to use pointers, use smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr` in this case).
- Better yet, omit pointers entirely. They are utterly unnecessary here. Unfortunately though, you cannot use `std::vector` with an incomplete class (the standard screwed up here). But you *can* (and should!) use `boost::container::vector`. Thus your tree node implementation becomes:

  ```
  struct Trie_node
  {
      boost::container::vector<Trie_node> children;
      bool is_word;

      Trie_node(int n)
          : children(n)
          , is_word(false)
      { }
  };
  ```

… There’s more but these are the essential points that will help reduce code complexity.

Comment: Some of my suggestions from http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18776/use-trie-data-structure-to-solve-the-problem-of-clustering-anagrams are still missing in his revision, like the use of `for_each` and similar algorithms; I suppose he could take a look at those if he's done with yours and still wants to improve it further. Seems I missed a few as well reading your suggestions... :)

Comment: @Tom Oops, I hadn’t noticed the previous thread at all. Good job there.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you used wrong data structure for the task. All what you need is a simple dictionary (the c++ map class). The idea to find all anagrams for a specific word is the following:

step 1: building map structure based on the dictionary - the key is a sorted by symbols word, the value is the list of anagrams.

Example.

dictionary   : tac god act

the map structure will be:

act: [tac, act]
dgo: [god]

step 2: search - we take the checked words one by one, sort their chars and use the result string as a key.

checked words: cat dog

cat -> **act** (letters are sorted) -> get anagrams from the dictionary for the key **act** -> [tac, act]
dog -> **dgo** (lettes are sorted) -> get ananagrams from the dictionary for the key **dgo** -> [god]

Here is the complete python solution for the similar [puzzle](http://codercharts.com/puzzle/its-raining-anagrams) (it could be like a pseudocode for the solution), the first parameter is a dictionary file, the second is the list of the checked words:

```
import sys
checkwords = open(sys.argv[2]).read().split()
lens = set(len(word) for word in checkwords)
index = {}
for word in open(sys.argv[1]).read().split(): 
   if len(word) in lens:
    index.setdefault(''.join(sorted(word)), []).append(word)
for word in checkwords: 
   anagrams = index[''.join(sorted(word))]
   print str(len(anagrams)) + '\n' + '\n'.join(anagrams)
```

Comment: I don’t think the trie is the wrong data structure here. In fact, a trie *is* a lookup structure for string keys, and potentially more efficient than other general-purpose dictionaries.

Comment: 1. Dictionaries are built-in and high optimized classes that exist in every modern language. If you want to port code to python or ruby or java - you need to rewrite the Trie class.

2. Trie class is not memory efficient class - try to put the big dictionary into the trie.

Comment: So what? I’m assuming that the question was asked in a CS course in the context of tries. And in fact tries are a *very* common data structure because they are indispensable in many fields, and implementations exist for all relevant programming languages.

Comment: That trie structure doesn't support unicode strings - so it's just a show stopper for a real use and a good chance to fail the interview.

Comment: Superficial knowledge can be a dangerous thing so maybe you should just accept that I know what I’m talking about. Like I said, the trie in OP’s question is probably from the context of a CS course where this is irrelevant (forget Unicode! It only accepts lower-case letters). Likewise in interviews: just be able to *explain* the limitations. If that’s a show-stopper then the interviewer is an idiot. In general, a trie *can* be written with Unicode in mind but a restricted alphabet implementation is often sufficient / superior because of the special use-cases it’s employed to solve.

Comment: And to answer your other point: a well-written trie is more memory-efficient than other implementations; it only stores each common prefix once and has very limited overhead because the areas where tries are commonly applied ensure that many strings will have common prefixes and are short.

Comment: Ok. I've tested trie vs Set classes in java using 178 691 words dictionary. Here is the results: trie building time is about 5 times slower, trie search time is about 7 times slower. Memory consumption is about 7 times bigger. Enjoy. Here is the code: http://www.dropbox.com/sh/m8ocl4jycot9w5t/EMm8-DPTOl?lst

Comment: Added the python tests: the python trie is even worse - about 30 times slower and memory consumption is 70 times bigger.

Comment: Kudos for testing this. However, I keep telling people not to do microbenchmarks because they are hellishly hard to get right and even seasoned CS researchers routinely do them wrong. In your case for instance you were benchmarking the reading from file, which distorts the result due to several factors. Furthermore, the Java trie implementation can me made more efficient. The Python implementation is totally irrelevant since the built-in set is highly optimised C code – which trie implementation did you use? Was it also highly optimised C code?

Comment: But in fairness, even with a corrected trie Java implementation and an improved benchmark code my trie is about twice as slow as the set for insertion, and more than four times as slow for retrieval. I blame cache locality. In special fields tries are used with special string (not general purpose ones) such as DNA and this may change the numbers significantly. However, I cannot reproduce this at the moment: in each scenario the trie is slower. Maybe Java’s reference indirection simply prevents an efficient implementation in principle.